# Can't Get Data Loaded on First Row of UITableView

Tags: objective-c, parsing, uitableview

I'm trying to parse an HTML Data using `HTMLParser` (by Ben Reeves) and display results on UITableView. For some reasons I'm able to show up results only on last row of the tableView. Here's the code snippet:

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{   
    NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
    NSError *error = [request error];
    HTMLParser *parser = [[HTMLParser alloc] initWithData:responseData error:&error];
    HTMLNode *bodyNode = [parser body];
    arrayNodes  = [bodyNode findChildrenWithAttribute:@"class" matchingName:@"foo" allowPartial:NO];

    for (HTMLNode *arrayNode in arrayNodes) {

        NSString *footitle = [arrayNode allContents];
        NSLog(@"%@", footitle);

        fooLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 200, 30)];
        fooLabel.text = (@"%@", footitle);
        fooLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }

    [self.fooTableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section  {

    return [arrayNodes count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
    }

    // Configure the cell.

    // [self.arrayNodes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:fooLabel];

    return cell;
}
```

Where am I making the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (HTMLNode *arrayNode in arrayNodes) {

        NSString *footitle = [arrayNode allContents];
        NSLog(@"%@", footitle);

        fooLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 200, 30)];
        fooLabel.text = (@"%@", footitle);
        fooLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
```

You are creating fooLabel's with same Frame size and location as many as arrayNodes array.

then in [cell.contentView addSubview:fooLabel]; it is showing you the last value that label is updated with.
take out that fooLabel from for loop.

in your cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
HTMLNode* arrayNode = [arrayNodes objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrayNode allContents]];
```

Comment: I'm receiving EXC_BAD_ACCESS message.

Comment: Okay, sorted it out. Thanks for help. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the foolabel in your cellForRowAtindexPath method. Right now only one foolabel is created, and it is applied to each cell in turn and then set to the next cell, leaving it placed on the last cell. So instead you should do this:

-

```
 (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
    }

    // Configure the cell.

       HTMLNode *arrayNode = [arrayNodes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       NSString *footitle = [arrayNode allContents];

        UILabel *fooLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 200, 30)];
        fooLabel.text = (@"%@", footitle);
        fooLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];


    [cell.contentView addSubview:fooLabel];

    [fooLabel release];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I'm receiving EXC_BAD_ACCESS message. :(